# Subtract two properties in list with eachother

Tags: c#

I want to get the difference between two integers, in this case "Age" - subtract them.

Here my class and my list. I want to, with a method, take the age from Robin and Sara and show the age difference. Is this possible with LINQ or..?

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class LinqQuery
{
    private readonly List<Person> _persons = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person {FirstName = "Robin", LastName = "Blixt", Age = 29},
        new Person {FirstName = "Sara", LastName = "Johansson", Age = 44}
    };

    public IEnumerable<Person> GetAll()
    {
        return _persons;
    }

    public void difference()
    {
        ?????
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to use Linq for this?

Comment: @Rytmis, that was exactly my thought!

Comment: What happens when the list has three items? How about four? Five?

Comment: That boils down to asking the question: how would you define the "difference between ages" with anything other than two people?

Comment: Could you show me an example?

Comment: An example of what, exactly? Thinking about the problem you are trying to solve?-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use lambda expression to find specified index if FirstName is youre key and you have more items than two. 
Please note that I did not check any erros (empty list etc.)

```
 public void diff() 
    { 

                int indxRobin = lst.FindIndex((item) => { return item.FirstName == "Robin"});
                int indxSara =  lst.FindIndex((item) => { return item.FirstName == "Sara"});

                return lst[indxRobin].Age - lst[indxSara].Age;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a cross-join you could calculate the age difference for all permutations in the list.

Of course, this is very crude and gives all duplicates, but it's easy from there to remove the duplicates in the query.

```
public void Difference()
{
    var ageDifferences = from p1 in _persons
                         from p2 in _persons
                         select new
                         {
                             P1FullName = p1.FirstName + " " + p1.LastName,
                             P2FullName = p2.FirstName + " " + p2.LastName,
                             AgeDifference = Math.Abs(p1.Age - p2.Age)
                         };

    foreach (var item in ageDifferences)
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("{0} and {1} have {2} years of age difference.", item.P1FullName, item.P2FullName, item.AgeDifference);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Thanks, @Tim Schmelter for the suggestion :)

```
public void difference()
{
    int sara= _persons.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.FirstName=="Sara").Age;
    int robin=_persons.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.FirstName=="Robin").Age;
    int difference= Math.abs(sara-robin);

    Console.ReadKey(); 
}
```

Comment: well ugly is okey but it doesn't compile.

Comment: That won't compile, because the result of both of your `Select`s is an `IEnumerable<int>`, not just `int`. OTOH, if you use `Single`, `First` or their `OrDefault` counterparts, you'll end up with an `InvalidOperationException` if more than one person with those first names exists in the list.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I didn't check before posting. Forgive my noobness. I've updated the answer. Also, it is a direct response to OP's question, so I'm not taking into account whether more than one person with those names exists in the list..

Comment: @Rytmis `First` and `FirstOrDefault` does not throw any exception if more than one is found. It simply returns the first one.

Comment: This is still not correct. You can work with a copy of it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jqZ4H8). FirstOrDefault expects a predicate, not an int.

Comment: @Minh: you probably want: `saraAge=_persons.First(p=>p.Name=="Sara").Age`

Comment: @Default Ah, sorry, of course. The idea in my head was that First/FOD is still not correct by any reasonable definition, but I lumped them all together in a moment of confusion. My apologies. :)